# Simple data set storage, use enumeration or database?

Tags: android

I have to store all the building name with their abbreviation in my app. There are actually about 200 buildings in my school. And the data looks like

```
Physics Builiding | PHYS
```

just full name plus abbreviation.

So I should better use what kind of way to store these data? Enumeration or database?

The reason I prefer enum is because it's really simple to use and there is not much data to store. Only I have to do is just declare 200 entries like this

```
PHYS("Physics Building")
```

but I worry about the performance issue. Will that happen if there are like 200 entries in the enum?

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd plonk them into an enum and not worry about it.  You can recompile your app a lot faster than the school can build a new building.

As for performance, write a test and try it.  You may have issues with your UI (long pick lists get tedious) but that would happen regardless.  My guess is that this is a nonissue.